# How can I install pgtap on rds postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, installation

I am using postgresql 10.7 under AWS RDS.

I downloaded `pgtap-1.0.0.zip` from https://pgxn.org/dist/pgtap/ because I saw an article in AWS forums saying you can just run `pgtap.sql` yourself.

However, in the zip file there is no `pgtap.sql` but a `pgtap.sql.in`...

I am using a Windows client. Tried to run `make` in wsl but complains about "pg_config: not found" while there is a `pg_config.EXE` in my `PATH`.

It did produce a `pgtap.sql` but running it fails on view "tap_funky" because it tries to use a non existing column `pg_catalog.pg_proc.prokind`

I replaced the missing `prokind` column by a hard coded "f" for (normal function) and got something apparently working but it creates everything in the *public* schema.

I tried to run that script in a specific schema "pgtap" but it failed straight way. Is there a proper way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of May 2019 pgTAP is an extension in RDS postgres version 11.2, (not version 10,7 however) according to 
https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/05/amazon-rds-postgresql-supports-minor-version-112/